# Python - Downloading a .exe file from the internet

Tags: python, execution, download

In the process of creating an auto-updater for my program, and I'm having trouble successfully downloading an .exe file.

What I was doing was something like this:

```
import urllib

url = '--insert-url--'

f = urllib.urlopen(url)
file = f.read()
f.close
f2 = open('download.exe', 'w')
f2.write(file)
f2.close
```

I encountered no errors while downloading, but when I try to run the execution, I get the following error:

> The version of this file is not
>   compatable with the version of Windows
>   you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information to see whether you
>   need an x86(32-bit) or an x64 (64-bit)
>   version of the program, and then
>   contact the software publisher.

I uploaded the execution myself and it worked fine before.

I also tried some various other methods for downloading that I found, which resulted in the same error, and I also tried uploading to different sites to make sure that wasn't it.

Is there a special way I need to do this?

EDIT:

I did some further testing with the download. I ran the program (I'm using what Spencer posted now) on a different computer -- a 32-bit system. (Mine is a 64-bit.) I don't get the error on that computer, but when I run the program, the command line comes up, as it is a command-line style .exe that I'm using as my test download, but the blinking white entry bar thing just bounces all over the place before I have to end the program, so something is obviously getting corrupted.

Also, would the downloading process be possible with a Batch file? This would almost be easier as the program is going to have to restart to begin using the new update anyway, as it is using an entirely new .exe. (I'm going to use py2exe for making the program an .exe.)

Comment: Since the file extension is '.exe' I assume you're doing this on Windows. Try changing the mode on the `f2` file to `'wb'` to write it in binary mode. The default is text mode while will change all the newline charcters (bytes) encountered into carriage-return + newlines.

Comment: If you download it manually (by visiting it over a webbrowser) and execute it, do you face the same problem?

Comment: @Senthil It works fine if I download it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official python docs for urllib:

> One caveat: the read() method, if the
>   size argument is omitted or negative,
>   may not read until the end of the data
>   stream; there is no good way to
>   determine that the entire stream from
>   a socket has been read in the general
>   case.

an alternative from the same library would be

```
import urllib

url = '--insert-url--' 

filename = 'download.exe'  
urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Comment: … very interesting, I hadn't realized that. If this turns out to be the solution, please comment here so I'll notice it.

Comment: It seems to speed up the download, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you need to include the `b` (binary) flag in your call to `open`:

```
import urllib

url = '--insert-url--'

f = urllib.urlopen(url)
file = f.read()
f.close()
f2 = open('download.exe', 'wb')
f2.write(file)
f2.close()
```

Also, you've omitted the parents in your calls to `.close()`. Not sure if that's a problem with your understanding or your example, but I've fixed it in the code above.

Also, if your `.exe` is big, you may want to write it to the file as you download it (currently you're reading the entire thing into memory). That would look something like:

```
f2 = open("download.exe", "wb")
try:
    while True:
        data = f.read(4096)
        if not data:
            break
        f2.write(data)
finally:
    f.close()
    f2.close()
```

Comment: That's strange. Can you diff the `.exe` downloaded with Python to the “working” `.exe` to see the differences? (I don't use Windows so I can't recommend a diff tool… But I'm sure Google will have some suggestions)

Comment: I used WinDiff and the only difference it found was that they had different creation dates.

Comment: You have to be careful with diff programs, if they don't do a binary diff then they may give you a false negative.

Comment: Indeed, windiff doesn't support binary comparisons.

Comment: Anyone know a free diff program that does support binaries?

Comment: @Adam Seitz on the command line, fc is microsoft's version of diff. It allows for binary comparisons between files. http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html has more info, but the primary bit is the /B switch for binary comparison.

Comment: Can you publish a link to the file?

Comment: *Hits head on desk*

After looking to publish a link to the file, I discovered the link I was using was the url to the download page and not the file itself.

The methods both Spencer and David provided worked perfectly. Thanks for helping me find my stupidity! :D

Comment: No problem, that's what stack overflow is for. :)

Comment: No problem. And thanks for coming back and posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think maybe you were having a different problem.

> My specs: Python3.X, installed via Homebrew. Using Python's urllib.request module, as it is the currently supported one.

I think that you were downloading a html page, which re-routed you to the download link. This is especially the case if you are trying to download from link. Many websites, and servers, have you click a button, which will provide a different url to download from.

For instance, if you try to download any [Microsoft link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533), like the FCIV checksum program, the download button actually routes you through a different url.

---

## Answer

My suggestion is that you load up the byte file you downloaded in your original answer as a .htm/l file. From here, you can try to find a url with an application extension;

For instance, if you stick with the [FCIV](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533) example, you will download something that give the same error:

> The version of this file is not compatable with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86(32-bit) or an x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

On closer inspection, if you load this file up as a .htm/l file, you can search for the x86 string and discover that it is on a url with actual name `https://download.microsoft.com/download/c/f/4/cf454ae0-a4bb-4123-8333-a1b6737712f7/Windows-KB841290-x86-ENU.exe` After which, if you try your download in the OP with this new url/https request, you will actually have a .exe that is correct.

---

**EDIT** Sorry, this answer may only apply to Python3.X in the year 2017. The answer is a little late to the original question asked 6 years ago. Also, the other answers and comments about the `b` flag in file writing is correct. The file should be opened with `wb` permissions.